# Is there a 'Subscription Cart' software available?

Tags: php, shopping-cart, subscription

I have a website, whereby members pay an annual feel. Initially the members were a few now it has fun into hundreds. Now I have to check existing members manually to see if their subscription is going to expire.

Is there a online service similar to a shopping card in e-commerce where I just give this software the details of members and this software reminds members that their subscription is going to expire, and will send notifications until their payments are settled?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of carts and scripts that will assist with subscription management but the more important component to this is your payment gateway. What you really want is a gateway that supports automated recurring billing (ARB) and then look for scripts that specifically support that gateway and also create ARB transactions.  With ARB, you don't worry as much about collections as the card will continue to be charged every anniversary until it reaches a pre-defined number of charges, the card expires, or the cardholder cancels the service.

To use a specific example, both Paypal and Authorize.net support ARB transactions. If I am running a WordPress site, I will want to find a membership management plugin that specifically supports PayPal or Authorize.net and can also creates the ARB transaction type.  That narrows the universe of available membership plugins down to a manageable 4 or 5 common plugins and I can then evaluate from there.

Answer (score 0):

*Most* carts or payment processors will offer this, though it's sometimes an addon. If you don't see them specifically refer to subscriptions, you might also see if they offer "recurring payments."